# Поиск подстроки по маске

Tags: c#, строки, подстрока

Нужно найти все варианты вхождения строки-шаблона в исходную строку.

В строке-шаблоне могут быть любые символы, а также `*` (обозначает подстановку в эту позицию >=0 любых символов). Знаю, как сделать, используя регулярные выражения, но их использовать нельзя. Желательно вообще ограничиться наивным поиском.

Пример1:

> Строка "abc"
>   Строка-шаблон "*"
>   Возвращает : "a","b","c","ab","bc","ac","abc"

Пример2:

> Строка "cabccbacbacab"
>   Строка-шаблон "ab**bac"
>   Возвращает : "abccbac"